# Disable Fluidbox.js on mobile devises?

Tags: jquery

I'm using [fluidbox.js](https://github.com/terrymun/Fluidbox).

In the documentation it recommends to disabling it on mobile devises.

So, I'm trying to implement a script which does this. Unfortunately it's not working and the console isn't throwing up any issues...

```
if($(window).width() < 540 ){
$(function () {
        $('a').fluidbox();
});
}
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

As I understand it the script is saying fire if the viewport is greater than 540px.

In short, I want to disable `$('a').fluidbox();` when a user views website on mobile.

Comment: You could try http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: Not sure what this is, is there any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Add this function to your js

```
window.mobilecheck = function() {
  var check = false;
  (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
  return check;
}
```

Then you do

```
if(window.mobilecheck === true){
  alert('is mobile!');
}else{
  alert('is not);
  $('a').fluidbox();
}
```

Comment: So I'm clear, drop the first part into a separate `script` then call it with the second part. Then is will disable the `fluidbox.js` script on mobile devises? I'm pretty new to js.

Comment: You can add it anywhere in your js block because the function is saved in the global "window" scope. This code will append fluidbox to your $('a') elements only if is not a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for tablet and wider using the window resize event, which handles it even when a desktop browser is resized to mobile (e.g. during testing a new website).

```js
// ADDING WINDOW RESIZE START AND RESIZE END EVENTS

var _lastWindowWidth = 0;

(function ($) {

    var d = 250, t = null, e = null, resizeend, resizestart, r = false;

    resizeend = function () {

        r = false;
        //console.log("resizeend fired");
        $(window).trigger('resizeend', e);
    };

    resizestart = function () {

        e = event || e;

        clearTimeout(t);

        if (!r) {

            //console.log("resizestart fired");
            $(window).trigger('resizestart', e);
            r = true;
        }

        if (_lastWindowWidth != $(window).outerWidth()) {

            _lastWindowWidth = $(window).outerWidth();

            t = setTimeout(resizestart, d);

        } else {

            t = setTimeout(resizeend, d);
        }
    };

    $(window).on('resize', function (event) {

        var retry = setTimeout(resizestart, 0);
    });

}(jQuery));


// WATCHING RESIZE EVENTS AND DISABLE/ENABLE FLUIDBOX

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on("resizestart", function () {

        $(".fluidbox-image > a")
            .trigger("destroy.fluidbox");

        $(".fluidbox-image > a").on("click", function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    $(window).on("resizeend", function () {

        if ($(window).innerWidth() >= 540) {

            $(".fluidbox-image > a").off("click");

            $(".fluidbox-image > a").fluidbox();
        }
    });

    $(window).trigger("resizestart");
    $(window).trigger("resizeend");
});
```